# Script para saber si todos los números de un array son iguales

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente script

```
function checkPares($numero) {
    $numero = str_split($numero);
    $pares = 0;
    if($numero[0]==$numero[1]) $pares = 1;
    return $pares;
}
```

Lo uso para saber si los 2 números de un array son iguales array(1,1) si todos los números del array son iguales retorna true, de lo contrario retorna false.

El problema es que tengo que hacer la misma verificación hasta con 6 números y no sé muy bien como hacerlo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Deberias de poner un ejemplo del array de entrada y la salida esperada.

Comment: Seria basicamente lo mismo. Los valores por ejemplo $arr = array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1), si todos son iguales que retorne true, si no, false.

Answer (score 5):

Lo puedes hacer de una forma muy sencilla, haciendo uso de `array_unique()`. Después de aplicarle el **unique** le haces un `count()` y si este te da resultado **1**, entonces en tu arreglo todos los números eran iguales, de lo contrario hay números diferentes.

```
$arreglo = array_unique($arreglo);
$cont    = count($arreglo);
return ($cont === 1) ? true : false;
```

Le decimos que si el `$cont` es igual a 1 nos retorne `true`, si es diferente retorna `false`.

Comment: por mejorar, puede ser solo `return ($cont === 1) `

Comment: En una sola línea sería: **`return count(array_unique($arr)) === 1 ? true : false;`** +1 por tu excelente respuesta.

Comment: En teoría no haría falta asignar los valores de retorno con el ?, Ya que el === te devolvería directamente true o false... `return count(array_unique($arr)) === 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera de hacerlo sería con [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$areEquals=count(array_count_values($arr)) === 1 ? true : false;
```

### Pruebas

```
$arr=array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
$areEquals=count(array_count_values($arr)) === 1 ? true : false;
var_dump($areEquals);
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(true)
```

---

```
$arr=array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0);
$areEquals=count(array_count_values($arr)) === 1 ? true : false;
var_dump($areEquals);
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(false)
```